Boot error after uprading from 23.10 to 24.04 LTS
I have a VM running with VMWare which has Ubuntu 23.10. It is an Ubuntu server. The output of the file/etc/os-release is:
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 23.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="23.10"
VERSION="23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)"
VERSION_CODENAME=mantic
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=mantic
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

I was able to upgrade without any issue to 24.04 LTS by issuing the following commands:
apt update
apt upgrade
reboot
apt dist-upgrade
do-release-upgrade

I checked that /etc/os-release is showing the right version and all is good:
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

The problem is that when i reboot my VM, i had the following errors:
error: symbol 'grub_abort' not found.
error: sparse file not allowed.
error: sparse file not allowed.
452: out of range pointer: 0xbff03600

Aborted. Press any key to exit

I could find on the internet some information stating to edit the /etc/default/grub and do some changes but i would like to understand what is happening first. Especially that with the version 23.10, i never had to change anything to grub and the VM was booting normally.
Any ideas?
